# Why does the recyclerview data loads only when the button is clicked the second time

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app based on placement. I have used firebase realtime database for this. I am matching company name from the "Job Post" db and "Applied Candidate" db, so that only applied candidates detail for that particular company will be displayed. Everything is working fine but the issue is the recyclerview's data loads only when the button is clicked the second time.

```
public class AppliedCandidateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbarAppliedcandidate;
    RecyclerView rvAppliedCandidate;
    List<appliedData> ls;
    String compNameposted;

    AppCandidateAdapter adapter;

    DatabaseReference dbJobPost,dbAppliedCandidate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.applied_candidate);

        toolbarAppliedcandidate = findViewById(R.id.toolbarAppliedcandidate);
        rvAppliedCandidate = findViewById(R.id.rvAppliedCandidate);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbarAppliedcandidate);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Applied Candidate");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        rvAppliedCandidate.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvAppliedCandidate.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ls = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new AppCandidateAdapter(getApplicationContext(),ls);
        rvAppliedCandidate.setAdapter(adapter);

        getCompany();
        matchCompanyName();
}

    void getCompany()
    {
        //To retrieve company name
        dbJobPost = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Job Post").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

        dbJobPost.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    PostJobData postJobData = ds.getValue(PostJobData.class);
                    compNameposted = postJobData.getCompName().toString();

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),postJobData.getCompName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }

    void matchCompanyName()
    {
        //To retrieve data of applied candidate for particular company
        dbAppliedCandidate = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Applied Candidate");

        dbAppliedCandidate.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds1 : ds.getChildren())
                    {
                        appliedData data = ds1.getValue(appliedData.class);
                        String compName = data.getCompName().toString();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),compName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if(compName.equals(compNameposted))
                        {

                            ls.add(data);
                        }
                        else if(ls.isEmpty()== true){
                            Toasty.info(AppliedCandidateActivity.this,"No One Applied Yet!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG,true).show();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public class AppCandidateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppCandidateAdapter.AppCandidateViewHolder>{
        List<appliedData> appliedDataList;
        Context context;

        public  AppCandidateAdapter(Context mcontext,List list){
            this.context = mcontext;
            this.appliedDataList = list;

        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public AppCandidateViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.applied_candidate_compside,parent,false);
            return new AppCandidateViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AppCandidateViewHolder holder, int position) {
            appliedData data = appliedDataList.get(position);
            holder.tvCandidateName.setText(data.getName());
            holder.tvCandidateAppliedPost.setText(data.getPosition());
            holder.tvCandidateQual.setText(data.getQualification());
            holder.tvCandidateSkills.setText(data.getSkills());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return appliedDataList.size();
        }

        class AppCandidateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView tvCandidateName,tvCandidateAppliedPost,tvCandidateQual,tvCandidateSkills;
            Button btnDeleteCandidate,btnSendMail;

            public AppCandidateViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                tvCandidateName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCandidateName);
                tvCandidateAppliedPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCandidateAppliedPost);
                tvCandidateQual = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCandidateQual);
                tvCandidateSkills = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCandidateSkills);
                btnDeleteCandidate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteCandidate);
                btnSendMail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnSendMail);


            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to notify adapter from `matchCompanyName` inside `onDataChange` when you done adding data in the list i.e after the for loop.

Comment: Please never leave `onCancelled` empty, as you're ignoring possible errors that way. Its minimum implementation should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `onDataChange` *does* get called, successfully reads the `PostJobData` data from the snapshot, and adds it to `ls`, you're not telling Android that the list has changed. Only once you notify the adapter of the change, will it rerender the view.

```
dbJobPost = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Job Post").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

dbJobPost.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            PostJobData postJobData = ds.getValue(PostJobData.class);
            compNameposted = postJobData.getCompName().toString();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify the adapter
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not working properly and the else loop is also getting executed simultaneously. The same problem continues

Comment: You'll have to do a bit better than "it's not working". Does your `onChange` get called? If so, and you step through it in a debugger, does it go into the loop? Does it get the `postJobData` as you expected? Does it reach the (new) `notifyDataSetChanged` call? Without you telling us exactly what happens, it's unlikely anyone will spot more problems at this point than what I (and ADM) already did.

Comment: Everything is working fine. The only issue is that the data is displayed only when the button is clicked 2nd time

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger? Did it reach the (new) call to `notifyDataSetChanged`? That should refresh the adapter.

Comment: Yes Sir , It goes through 'notifyDataSetChanged'. But it works sometime and sometime it is not working

Comment: So that's different from before isn't it? If so, that indicates the `notifyDataSetChanged` **does** make a difference, which is good. At that point, you will need to figure out what is different between when it works and it doesn't work. Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend inspecting all variables, stepping into all methods, and seeing where the difference is.

Comment: Hey @NishmithaNaik Did you make any more progress on this?